# An Interface cannot implement in PHP?

Tags: php

I was making an interface and I wanted the classes to implement Iterator. But, apparently this is a syntax error:

```
interface iQuestions implements Iterator {}
```

My first thought was to copy the functions from the Iterator interface, but then I thought that violates DRY... or does it?

Is there a way I can do what I want, namely to require all questions to implement Iterator? OR perhaps am I over-engineering this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interface cannot implement other interface. It can extend it.

```
interface iQuestions extends Iterator {}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#language.oop5.interfaces.examples.ex2

[implement definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/implement)

Comment: All good man :) Just think of me as your little minion hahaha